# Javascript closure and its scope

Tags: javascript, closures

```
for (var i=0, link; i<5; i++) {
    link = document.createElement("a");
    link.innerHTML = "Link " + i;
    link.onclick = function (num) {
        return function () {
            alert(num);
        };
    }(i);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
}
```

Since the nested function is a closure it has a reference to the `num` argument ,the `num` argument at the end of the loop  is 4 .Now when the first element gets clicked why does it alerts 1 ?It should alert 4 .What is the reason for alerting 1 ?Dont it reference to `num` argument?or what is the reason?

But here the case is different:

```
function foo(x) {
    var tmp = 3;
    return function (y) {
       alert(x + y + (++tmp));
    }
}
var bar = foo(2); // bar is now a closure.
bar(10);
```

The above function will alert 16, because bar can still refer to arg `x` and `tmp`, even though it is no longer directly inside the scope.

This proves that the closure also have reference to arguments value than why the above code not alerting 4 everytime?

Comment: It's alerting `1` when clicking on the first element since you are passing the argument `i` at the current iteration to the inner `onclick` function which has the argument `num`.

Comment: [This question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) has some great answers that can help you understand closures

Comment: It actually should be alerting 0, since thats the first # that you pass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  for (var i=0, link; i<5; i++) {  //i starts at 0 and iterates up to 4
        link = document.createElement("a");
        link.innerHTML = "Link " + i;


         link.onclick = function (num) {
            //num is never changed within this function, and is equal
            //to the value of i when it was passed in

            return function () { alert(num);};

        }(i);  //i is passed here
        //that sets num to the current value of i for each link

        document.body.appendChild(link);
   }
```

For the first link num will be 0, because `i` was one when it was passed to the outer function.  i is then iterated for each turn of the loop and will be a different value for each link.

The pattern here is a very common pattern for preserving the current value of a loop iteration in callbacks/event bindings.

Comment: so wont the event handler reference to the arg num on the first click?

Comment: yes.  and `num` is preserved by the closure to be the value of `i` when the onclick property was first set.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is the classic example to *avoid* that clicking on the first element will give you 4 instead of 1, which should be the most expected value.

If you want it to alert 1, then just do this:

```
link.onclick = function() {alert(i);};
```

But honestly, what would be the point of this? All 4 links would alert 4...